# Injecting Runtime Data Into Dependencies

Tags: c#, dependency-injection

I have a web application with a fairly complex process that starts by getting a bunch of data from the database to use throughout the process (the lifetime of this process and data is a single request).  The data is fetched from a few different tables and is based on some data passed in at runtime.

The entry point of this process calls methods from it's dependencies that use this data.  It doesn't feel quite right however, as it seems like the dependencies should really have dependencies on DataAccessor rather than initializing it within the entry method (DoStuff) and then passing it all over throughout the process, but since DataAccessor has state based on the data passed in to the DoStuff method, I can't really do that.

```
public class Service {

    private readonly IRepository repo;
    private readonly Analyzer analyzer;
    private readonly Validator validator;     

    public Service(IRepository _repo, Validator _validator, Analyzer _analyzer){
        repo = _repo;
        validator =_validator;
        analyzer = _analyzer;
    }

    public void DoStuff(string sourceId, AnalysisConfig config, List<Item> items){

        // go get data used for this process based on the runtime data
        // it's going to be a subset of the database data based on the runtime data passed into this method
        DataAccessor data = BuildDataAccesor(config, items);

        foreach(var item in items){
            ProcessItem(sourceId, config, data, item);
        }

    }

    //this method doesn't really need all these parameters, I'm only passing them in so they make it through to the other dependencies
    public void ProcessItem(string sourceId, AnalysisConfig config, DataAccessor data, Item item){

        //do some stuff

        //then
        analyzer.AnalyzeItem(sourceId, config, data, item);
        validator.ValidateItem(sourceId, data, item );

   }


    // this goes an gets some data from the database to store in memory for the length of the DoStuff method
    public DataAccessor BuildDataAccesor(AnalysisConfig config, List<Item> items){
        DataAccessor data = new DataAccessor();
        data.FooCollection = repo.GetSomeData(config);
        data.BarCollection = repo.GetSomeOtherData(config);
    }


}
```

And the Dependencies

```
public class Analyzer{

    public void AnalyzeItem(string sourceId, AnalysisConfig config, DataAccessor data, Item item){
       //do some stuff with the item looking up stuff from the data blob
       data.FooCollection.Get(item.Id);
    }



}
```

and the other

```
public class Validator {

    public void ValidateItem(string sourceId, DataAccessor data, Item item){
       //do some stuff with the item looking up stuff from the data blob
    }

}
```

It's going to be more complex than this, but I think this captures the gist.  Is there a way to refactor this so that I can initialize DataAccessor with runtime data and inject into the dependencies of Service?

Comment: Sounds like you could use an `IDataAccessorFactory` that you can call `DataAccessor Create()` on.

Comment: What's the best way to get that to the dependencies of the main class though?  They can't have the factory as a dependency, because the factory needs runtime data from the DoStuff method to initialize the DataAccessor.

Comment: Some interesting reading https://blogs.cuttingedge.it/steven/posts/2015/code-smell-injecting-runtime-data-into-components/